# Does it help in terms of speed to use "color: #000" instead of color: black

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which one is faster: hex color codes or color names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640575/which-one-is-faster-hex-color-codes-or-color-names)

In terms of page rendering speed, does it make any diference to the browsers if the color in the css file is written as

```
color: #000;
```

opposed to

```
color: black;
```

Naturally, my guess would be it does not, but since I didn't find any viable resources about it on the net, I'm asking for your opinion and possibly a more detail explanation than to just 'no'.

Comment: At least `#000` save some bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the hex code is slightly faster because the browser doesn't have to look up and translate the word.

You can check this unofficial test http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4151070.htm?highlight=msg4158590, which supports the idea that it doesn't really make a noticeable difference :]