# How to put color border in my inputs in html

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone does anyone know how to put border color in any inputbox or selectbox if i click them? just like in the picture.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the `:focus` selector:

**HTML:**

```
<label for="my-text">My Label</label>
<input type="text" name="my-text" id="my-text" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]:focus { outline:1px solid red; }
```

OR

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #FF0000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: `outline` != `border`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
input[type=text]:focus { border-color: #f00; }
```

in your CSS. The important part for you is the :focus, but I'm including [text] here so you don't get funny-looking checkboxes, etc.

Comment: Always try to avoid using named colors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054520/it-is-recommendable-to-type-the-colors-name-instead-of-its-hex-value-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640575/which-one-is-faster-hex-color-codes-or-color-names