# Why does LESS convert #fff to white?

Tags: css, less, dotless

If I have:

```
.foo
{
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

LESS converts this to:

```
.foo
{
    background-color:white;
}
```

Why is this? Do browsers process named colours faster than HEX values?

I'm implementing LESS using [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/). Could this be carrying out the conversion? And if so why?

Comment: Does it, for example, convert `#00FA9A` to `MediumSpringGreen`? If not I'd argue they made a few exceptions for the benefit of the human reader.

Comment: I don't know why less is doing this but colours aren't faster than hex. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640575/which-one-is-faster-hex-color-codes-or-color-names)

Comment: SASS has the same problem. It's due to the way the CSS spec is implemented and color names can be compressed.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/343

I can't find anything definite, but there is a nice thread above that explains why it is done this way.

Comment: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/363

Comment: @Tomalak `#00FA9A` converts to `mediumspringgreen`.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the link, now I'm even more confused as to why this is happening!

Comment: @Curt Well then I'd argue somebody has lived out  their OCD and implemented a conversion for the named color table just because it exists. I cannot think of a good *technical* reason to convert hex to names.

Comment: Which version of Less are you using? For me, it doesn't convert hex values to color names. It would actually do the reverse when we assign `white` to a variable and use it for a property. [CodePen Sample](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/oIKhc).

Comment: The official Less compiler never did that (and I doubt any of Less compilers family does this too... Hmm, are you sure it's Less and not some other tool in your build chain?)

Comment: @seven-phases-max Ah, I'm using dotless to implement this in my ASP.NET MVC application. I didn't consider that this might be doing the conversion.

Comment: @Curt: Yes, it seems to be. Look at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Less-js-differences#color-compression) which lists differences between Dotless and Less.js. They are calling it color compression. *Note:* Although, the second statement seems contradictory with the first.

Comment: isnt the question rather why not convert it ? it shouldnt make any difference for you

Comment: @Curt: Yep, I see now you're right and `dotless` does this actually. Though there were some talks in a discussion list about changing this behavior. I can't find dotless release notes anywhere but it's possible they have fixed this in v1.4.0 or 1.4.1 (unless you're already using one of those and they still have not).

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the link, exactly what I was after. So the answer to my question is "In dotless we *favour* the color keyword". I don't think this as Christoph pointed out earlier this is worse for performance. So its odd they would enforce this. Please write an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Curt: Just out of curiosity, did you happen to come across any further information outside of SO on this item? Asking because I wasn't lucky. Please do not mistake this as pestering for acceptance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Differences between less.js and dotless

> **Color compression**
>
> **In dotless we favour the color keyword over the hex code, if one matches**. When compressing it chooses whichever is shorter.. e.g. #FFF, #FFFFFF, white then #FFF will be chosen, but in the case of red, the keyword red will be used.
>
> **In less.js every colour is replaced with a hex code.**

The above quote is from the **[official Dotless GitHub page](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Less-js-differences#color-compression).**

**Notes:**

1. The second part of that quote sounds a bit contradictory to the first one but I think the first statement is clear enough on the expected behavior.
2. As pointed out by [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640867/why-does-less-convert-fff-to-white#comment40073882_25640867) they were planning to fix this and as per [Issue #332's log](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/332) the `DisableColorCompression` flag has already been added to disable this compression.
3. The color keyword to hex code mapping seems to be maintained in [Color.cs](https://github.com/david-poirier/dotless/blob/223fd4439749524e4dab042de0e217cb5ba3a77d/src/dotless.Core/Parser/Tree/Color.cs) source file.
4. [Issue 317](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/317) and [Issue 168](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/168) are two other similar issues which are still in *open* status, so I am not sure if the `DisableColorCompression` flag addresses the hex code to color name conversion item fully.